# Как дать странице прогрузиться перед тем, как её парсить? - python

Tags: python, парсер

Привет, мне тут пришлось парсить этот сайт: [клац](https://shop124688769.world.taobao.com/search.htm?spm=a312a.7700824.w4002-11279144371.3.c2SR1p&_ksTS=1496435328918_319&callback=jsonp320&mid=w-11279144371-0&wid=11279144371&path=%2Fsearch.htm&search=y&csy=1&pv=20021:3226338).

Но не тут то было, нужный мне блок(точнее клиенту) подгружается, после загрузки страницы.

[image: **Этот блок**]

А библиотека `requests` (`python`), отсылает `html` сразу, не дожидаясь его загрузки. Кто подскажет, как решить это? Может, какая-нибудь другая библиотека?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Get page generated with Javascript in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8960288/4279)

Answer (score 1):

после загрузки страницы выполняется фоновый запрос к https://shop124688769.world.taobao.com/i/asynSearch.htm?_ksTS=1499894627777_319&callback=jsonp320&mid=w-11279144371-0&wid=11279144371&path=/search.htm&search=y&spm=a312a.7700824.w4002-11279144371.3.c2SR1p&csy=1&pv=20021%3A3226338 он и возвращает нужный вам блок, только используется JSONP поэтому перед парсингом нужно будет очистить ответ от вызова javascript функции.

Comment: И как же это сделать, если не секрет?)

Comment: @Penter, посмотрите код страницы и поймете о чем речь. Так же поставьте дополнения к браузеру, для анализа заговоловков и запросов.

Comment: @Igor, я не понял смыл этих сток: "очистить ответ от вызова javascript функции." html я видел, запросы и ответы сервера посмотрел и что мне с этим делать?

Comment: по ссылке пример уже устарел, поставьте анализатор заголовков в браузере, например http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/. Смотрим запрос и ответ, имитируем через request. Итоговую страницу возможно придется разобрать чем-то, чтобы убрать технический мусор.

Comment: Ссылка, которую я привел возвращает строку - "jsonp320(<hml-code>)" вам нужно извлечь подстроку <html-code> из ответа, и только потом пробовать парсить например с помощью beautifulsoup. Также если есть вопросы прсмотритесь к JSONP стандарту.

Comment: "html я видел, запросы и ответы сервера посмотрел и что мне с этим делать?" - парсить конечно, сами ведь написали что нужно парсить.

Answer (score 0):

Используй парсер вроде phantomJS, webkit или gecko. Окошко рисовать не обязательно. Будет полноценный браузер с кликом мышкой и прочим.